# How to disable Peek problem in VS Code on a MAC?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure how I got this, maybe via some extension that was installed on my VS Code, but I need to disable this.

[image]

Comment: What code language file are you editing?

Comment: I am editing python file

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no setting to disable/hide these "squiggly lines". VS Code indicates them as errors or "Problems" with your code, and it's always recommended to address the problems rather than to hide them.

But there are workarounds.

1. Change the color

   You can [customize the color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) to make it transparent:

   ```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
   }
   ```

   You can also customize it so that it looks like the editor background.

   ```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "editor.background": "#282a36",
       "editorError.foreground":  "#282a36",
   }
   ```

   If you are using a theme, you can get the theme's current value for `editor.background` by opening the command palette, then selecting "*Developer: Generate Color Theme from Current Settings*", which will open a JSON file containing all the theme colors. Look for `editor.background`.

   You could also set it to something that isn't as striking as bright red.

   Note that this way just hides the "squiggly lines". The errors will still show up in the **Problems** panel and when you hover your mouse over the line.

   [image]
2. Disable Python linting

   For Python, if you look at the **Problems** tab, the error is actually raised by the [Python Linters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) that come with VS Code and the Python extension. In my case, I'm using [`pylint`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint).

   You could disable these linters by calling the [Python: Enable Linting command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_disable-linting) command and setting it to **off**, or by putting this in your settings.json:

   ```
   "python.linting.enabled": false,
   ```

   Note that this way not just hides the red squiggly lines, but stops linting altogether, so you also won't see anything in the **Problems** panel.

   [image]

   This is harmful to the development process as it stops checking for "*syntactical and stylistic problems in your Python source code, which oftentimes helps you identify and correct subtle programming errors or unconventional coding practices that can lead to errors.*".

   **I don't recommend doing this.**

Comment: For option 1, just make them transparent - no need to match the editor background.